# VS Code not changing the Conda environment

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, anaconda3

VS Code: 1.56.2
Python Extension Installed.

I am able to run scripts in VS Code selecting the 'base' conda environment. However, when I created a new environment, say *new_env*, Its still not switching this environment. I updated the settings.json

```
"python.condaPath": "/Users/myuser/anaconda3/bin/conda",
"python.pythonPath": "/Users/myuser/anaconda3/envs/new_env/bin.python3.8",
```

If I select the terminal, it automatically calls, *conda activate new_env* but when I run this:

```
print(os.environ['CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV'])
```

I still get 'base' instead of 'new_env'. Any libs installed in new_env is promptly giving *ModuleNotFoundError*.

I have selected the correct interpreter multiple times, reloaded the VSC window but no help. Followed steps from https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments

Any pointers would be appreciated.